# Can I access this of an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, this

```
var b = {
    state: 'initial',
    initial: {
        onClick: function() {
            console.log(this);
        },
        x: 0,
    },
}
```

Hi, I want to know if its possible to access b object inside onClick function in the code above?

the output is `{x: 0, onClick: ƒ}` instead of `{state: 'initial', ... }`

Changing it to arrow func will output window object instead.

Im making an escape room game and kind of have a chicken & egg situation.

```
var spriteObject =
{
  img: null,
  INITIAL: {
    sourceX: 0,
    sourceY: 0,
    sourceWidth: 64,
    sourceHeight: 64,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 64,
    height: 64,
    isWithinBounds: function(x, y) {
      return x > this.x && x < this.x + this.width && y > this.y && y < this.y + this.height;
    },
  },
  
  state: 'INITIAL',
};
const inventoryItems = [];
let currentRoom = "kitchen";

const knife = {
  ...spriteObject,
  INITIAL: {
      ...spriteObject.INITIAL,
      x: 200,
      y: 162,
      sourceX: 1330,
      sourceY: 8,
      sourceWidth: 803,
      sourceHeight: 514,
      width: 803,
      height: 514,
      onClick: () => {
        inventoryItems.push(knife);
        layers.kitchen.sprites = layers.kitchen.sprites.filter(sprite => sprite !== knife);
      },
  },
  img: kitchenLayout,
};

const layers = {
  kitchen: {
    sprites: [knife],
  },
};

window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  const y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
  layers[currentRoom].sprites.forEach(sprite => {
    const currSprite = sprite[sprite.state];
    if (currSprite.onClick && currSprite.isWithinBounds(x, y)) {
      currSprite.onClick();
      render();
    }
  })
})
```

Let's say I have a kitchen room and a knife on the counter. I can pick the knife and put it in my inventory. The knife will have 3 different conditions: on the counter (initial), in inventory, and dull (after used). I am not sure if I want to model in inventory as a state, but I have trouble figuring out how to remove the knife from list of sprites in kitchen. It is doable in the code above but it seems to rely on the fact that I declare knife as a variable. I don't want to do this, in case I want to declare my items directly on the sprites array. I appreciate any hints, thanks

Comment: why don't use directly `b.whatyouneed` like `b.x` ?

Comment: A function is called later, so yes in theory you can as it'd be defined then.

Comment: b.initial.onClick cannot equal b.state as example initially cause it doesn't exist during initiating the object but if you avoid that you'll be fine; functions should be AOK.

Comment: The `this` context during the call time of `onClick` will always be the `initial` object of the object `b`. `initial` does never *"know"* about its parent structure as long as one does not provide a parent reference/link as direct property of `b.initial` itself. An [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is not capable of binding any `this` context. It features lexical scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use javascript classes for this. That way you can reference your current class as `this`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Please elaborate on how you would tackle the problem?

I thought this would be the least impactful change to get the code working for him. But please point me to a better way. Always open to learn :)